# Not quite similiarity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If I let $GL_r(\mathbb{R}) \times GL_s(\mathbb{R})$ act on the set of all $r \times s$ matrices by $(A,B) \cdot M = AMB^{-1}$, why am I able to reach a diagonal matrix with $0's$ and $1's$ along the diagonal?

It seems the idea is to say let $r < s$, find a square submatrix in $M$ and put it in Jordan form but I don't see how to do this. Thanks.

Comment: It's called `equivalence`  of matrices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of it in terms of linear maps and bases. Let $T:\mathbb{R}^s\to\mathbb{R}^r$ be a linear transformation. Let $v_1,\ldots,v_s,$ be a basis of $\mathbb{R}^s$, such that $v_{s-k+1},\ldots,v_s$, is a basis of $\ker T$. Let$$w_i:=T(v_i),\qquad i=1,\ldots,s-k.$$Then $w_1,\ldots,w_{s-k}$ are linearly independent. Extend the $w$'s to a basis of $\mathbb{R}^r$, and the matrix representing $T$ with respect to the $v$'s and the $w$'s has the desired form.

Answer (score 2):

Left multiplication by elementary matrices lets you get $AM$ to be upper triangular; that's called "Gaussian Elimination" or "row reduced echelon form" or something like that. Since elementary matrices are invertible, the product of all these elementary matrices is a matrix $A$ in $GL_r(\mathbb R)$. Similarly, right multiplication by elementary matrices lets you then turn $AM$ into $AMQ$ which is a diagonal matrix $D$. Right multiplying by a diagonal matrix that's the entry-by-entry inverse of $D$ (with $0$ entries becoming zeroes!), gives you a diagonal matrix of all zeroes and ones. Now let $B = (QD)^{-1}$ and you're done.

See also the wikipedia entry on Smith Normal Form, which discusses this in the case of integer matrices; following that with the "division" step then shows it works for real entries to give the result you need.